# Print variables inside jade file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, template-engine

I want to print default value for my forms textarea i have bellow code

```
 textarea(class="form-control",name="details")
     if restaurant.details
          #{restaurant.details}
```

but if my value ( restaurant.details ) is set it will apears like tag not text,
how can print text inside my textarea?

Comment: Can you share your output HTML? Or at least what values are in `restaurant.details`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `|` operator:

```
 textarea(class="form-control",name="details")
     if restaurant.details
       | #{restaurant.details}
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmhjG)

**From the [docs](http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/)**

> The simplest way of adding plain text to templates is to prefix the
>   line with a | character (pronounced "pipe").

Answer (score 4):

By using `!{...}` instead of `#{...}`, you will get string exactly without compilation / interpolation.